# Trying to style the active items on a foreach menu with submenu in php

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm really newbie in php and I'm styling a wordpress theme. I'm trying to add a class to the active items on a foreach custom menu with submenu items:

```
    <?php
        foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {

        $children = get_term_children($taxonomy->term_id, $taxonomy_name);
        $args = array(
          'hide_empty' => true,
          'order_by' => 'name',
          'parent' => $taxonomy->term_id
        );
        $children = get_terms($taxonomy_name, $args); 


        ?>
    <ul> 
        <li class="<?php echo (in_array($taxonomy->term_id, $active_terms) ? 'active' : '' )?>"><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($taxonomy->term_id, $taxonomy_name ) ?>"><?php echo $taxonomy->name ?></a></li>

        <?php if(!empty($children)) : ?>
            <ul class="<?php echo (in_array($taxonomy->term_id, $active_terms) ? 'active' : '' ) ?>" >
            <?php foreach($children as $child) : ?>
                <li class="<?php echo (in_array($child->term_id, $active_terms) ? 'active' : '' )?>"><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($child->term_id, $taxonomy_name ) ?>"><?php echo $child->name ?></a></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif;?>
<?php
      }?>
        </ul>
    <?php
    }  
?>
```

Is working fine but when I'm in a `<ul> $taxonomy` and no `<li>` must be active it also adds 'active' class to the first `<li>` subitem in the array. What I'm doing wrong? How I could fix that? I've been searching around but I'm really new on php and wordpress themes, any help is appreciated!

Thank you so much!

Comment: so your problem in <li> inside the big <ul> when there are no children .. right ?

Comment: well the problem is in <li> inside the inner <ul>, when i'm in the <ul> page where i display all the items in the array, the <li> for the first item on the array it becomes 'active', when it is not because i'm not in that page. I hope i'm explaining fine.

Answer (score 0):

This code looks fine. In sub-foreach li you have term:

```
in_array($child->term_id, $active_terms)
```

Check if *$child->term_id* and *$active_terms* are correct.

Comment: sorry for asking but how do I check it? :)
I think they are fine because they work and they are active when they have to be. The only problem is when i'm in inner <ul> page that the <li> for the first item in $taxonomy goes active.

Comment: Are you sure that this first "li" has class="active" in html code? If it's only look like active category but in generated html hasn't "active" class its problem with CSS.

Comment: Yes, the class 'active' its added on the html. It's not a problem with CSS.

Comment: So the problem is with get_term_children function. It gives you in one array: term object and children of this term. Look at get_term_children function code: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <?php foreach($children as $child) : ?>
    <?php if($child->term_id == $taxonomy->term_id) { continue;} ?>
    <li class="<?php echo (in_array($child->term_id, $active_terms) ? 'active' : '' )?>"><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($child->term_id, $taxonomy_name ) ?>"><?php echo $child->name ?></a></li>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you Marcin, but it keeps doing the same although you are right and is giving all the items in one array as you said. 

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if current url is the same of `href` attribute of links.

```
    <?php foreach($children as $child) : ?>
        <li class="<?php echo get_term_link($child->term_id, $taxonomy_name) == 'http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]' ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($child->term_id, $taxonomy_name ) ?>"><?php echo $child->name ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Is throwing me an error :(

PARSE ERROR: PARSE ERROR, EXPECTING `','' OR `';''

for this line `<li class="<?php echo (get_term_link($child->term_id, $taxonomy_name) == 'http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]') ? 'active' : '' )?>">`

Comment: Fixed the problem. Of course adapt it if your link format is different, for example in the href there is only $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]

Comment: Thanks. Now it's not adding 'active' when i'm on the <ul> but neither it's doing when i'm currently in the <li>, which is what I need in fact. I guess that may b this happens because the <ul> has <li> active categories also associated. May be there is a way that I only retrieve the first active category to <ul>?

Comment: You have to check the format of the link that    get_term_link($child->term_id, $taxonomy_name) outputs, if the link is full like    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36084404/ you have to compare with    http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] , while if it is like /questions/36084404/ you have to compare with    $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]

Comment: I think it's the first case; tried second anyway, but is still not working.

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the first category that <ul> is related to?

Comment: Sincerely, I'm not expert about Wordpress, I've used this solution in pure PHP and it is right.

Comment: Thanks Claudio, I must be missing something in the wordpress implementation or... no idea :D